# Tools for making Finder easier to use?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

I need the following tools for Finder.

- Launch a Terminal from Finder.
- Copy a path information from Finder.
- Make a new file from Finder. (not a new directory)

Any hints?

Comment: Launch a terminal from finder...can't you go to applications -> utilities -> Terminal?

Comment: i believe the idea is to launch Terminal with the cwd of Finder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FilePathCM](http://www.limit-point.com/Utilities/FilePathCM.html). FilePathCM is a contextual menu and menu bar item for copying the:

- POSIX path
- Server afp URL
- Abbreviated (Tilde) POSIX path
- POSIX path for Terminal.app
- HFS path
- Full name
- Display name
- Extension
- Windows style path

of Finder items (files, folders, volumes) to the clipboard.

To create a new file, see this link: http://www.webmonkey.com/2007/03/how_to_create_new_files_in_apple_s_finder/

To launch a terminal, I like answer from neoneye but I also use [DTerm](http://www.decimus.net/dterm.php).

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea how to create a new file from within the Finder, however..

[image: cdto logo]

### [cdto](http://code.google.com/p/cdto/)

Opens Terminal and cd's to the current Finder dir.

### [cdff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420456/open-terminal-here-in-mac-os-finder)

cdff allows you to open the current Terminal dir in the finder.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use **[Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com/)**

It is not a free application but you have 30 days to try it out. You can see a screencast [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/media.cocoatech.com/PF5OverviewSmall.mov).

It enables you to do the following from your requisites:

1. Launch a Terminal from Finder.
2. Copy a path information from Finder. (I don't know what you mean with this but it sure does the job).
3. Make a new file from Finder. (not a new directory)
   and any more...